# How to append nodes from variable (JSON like) into Dynatree

Tags: jquery, dynatree

Can you help me how to append nodes into Dynatree?

I have variable res that contains full node tree:

```
var res = '['
res += '{ "title": "Node 1", "key": "k1"},'
res += '{ "title": "Node 2", "key": "k2"},'
res += '{ "title": "Node 3", "key": "k3"}'
res += ']';
```

How can I add those nodes into next tree?

```
$("#tree3").dynatree({
    children: [

          // here , somehow...?

    ]
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#tree3").dynatree({
    children: jQuery.parseJSON(res)
});
```